# How to read MP3 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3, wav, watermark

I am currently working on watermarking audio files in Matlab for a mathematics research project. So far I have been able to read wav files using wavread in Matlab. However, because wav files are very large, the resulting data is also large. Therefore, in order to simplify this I would like to know how I would be able to read an mp3 file in Matlab. So far I have only tried to read an mp3 by using dsp.AudioFileReader. However, the resulting data only contains 0's and a few other numbers, which is clearly not the correct data. Would someone please be able to help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
hfr = dsp.AudioFileReader('yourfile.mp3');
hplay = dsp.AudioPlayer('SampleRate',sample_rate_here);
 while ~isDone(hfr)
         audio = step(hfr);
         step(hplay, audio);
 end
```

Comment: This seems to work only with fixed bitrate. Is vbr also possible?

Comment: you also work with vbr, see this exemple [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10061-vorbis-ogg-audio-encodingdecoding/content/ogg_toolbox/oggwrite.m)

Comment: I tried using the code above, 'hfr = dsp.AudioFileReader('yourfile.mp3')," but the resulting data mainly consisted of all 0's, which is obviously not correct. I have been continuing to search online but so far I still cannot find a way to read mp3 files.