# How to import a mp3 file in Matlab 7?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to import a mp3 song into Matlab 7 and apply different filters on it using sptool and fdatool.

I have tried to import using 'audioread' for wav file, it does not exist in Matlab 7. I tried 'wavread' for wav file, it says my audio compression is not supported.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266087/how-to-read-mp3-in-matlab) tells a way but error in Matlab 7 again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simple google search - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6152-mp3write-and-mp3read

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html

Comment: Thanks @Andrey ! Now have to see it works for me or not. BTW _audioread_ not supported in Matlab 7.

Comment: @Andrey and others: Matlab 7 (R14) is [from 2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history) so links to current documentation aren't likely to be helpful. Here is the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14/helpdesk.html). I think that you may need to convert to a WAV file outside of Matlab (a lossless conversion, but the resultant file is much bigger) and use [`wavread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14/techdoc/ref/wavread.html). Or, better, figure out how to upgrade your Matlab.